# As a squad leader I can't set squad orders

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

Since upgrading premium (PC about 2-3 months ago) I can still spot but I can't set squad orders. Has something changed or is it a bug? There have been several updates since then and I can't see anyone else reporting this problem.

When squad leader I aim at a flag/objective hit 'q' and nothing happens. I've reset my input settings, I've re-installed BF3 (I was reformatting anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was changed a while ago I believe. Now to set an order to an objective, you should press and hold <kbd>Q</kbd> (or the other button if you changed the default layout) until the menu appears. After that, at the bottom you will see a green line, choose it and the order will be set.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

The text in green can be translated as: "Give order". *(Yes, it's the Russian version of BF3)*

Comment: Awesome thank you, I'm at work now but I'll check as soon as I get home :)

Comment: after the edit I don't even need to check :) thanks again

Comment: It doesn't seem to work well or at all sometimes when in a vehicle.